# What are the number of ACKs sent after receiving more than 2 full-size segment?

Tags: networking, tcp

TCP RFC mentions that the receiver should send an ACK for every 2 full size segment it receives (assuming they are inorder) and should not delay an ACK.

Considering the window size is 8 segments and sender sends 8 full segments, does this mean, the receiver sends 4 ACKs even though it has received 8 segments?

Can it not acknowledge all 8 segments with one ACK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ill just copy paste the important Part of the RFC right in here:

> 4.2.3.2  When to Send an ACK Segment
>
> ```
>         A host that is receiving a stream of TCP data segments can
>         increase efficiency in both the Internet and the hosts by
>         sending fewer than one ACK (acknowledgment) segment per data
>         segment received; this is known as a "delayed ACK" [TCP:5].
>
>         A TCP SHOULD implement a delayed ACK, but an ACK should not
>         be excessively delayed; in particular, the delay MUST be
>         less than 0.5 seconds, and in a stream of full-sized
>         segments there SHOULD be an ACK for at least every second
>         segment.
> ```

The Full RFC can be found here: [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-4.2.3.2)

Comment: So you are agreeing to the fact that we need to send 4 ACKs in case we receive 8 segments..?

Comment: I MAY would implement it in another way, but RFC´s are binding, if you use them in  public. So yes, i agree that you need too sent at least 4 ACK when you receive 8 segments.